# Получить значения полей с класа, который екстендится, в базовом

Tags: php, extend

У меня есть базовый класс `BaseCommand` примерно такого вида:

```
abstract class BaseCommand {

function handle(array $update)
{
    $this->processCommand();
}

abstract function processCommand();

abstract function defaultCommand();
abstract function settingsCommand();
abstract function startCommand();
```

}

И все другие классы-обработчики от него екстендятся:

```
class SelectLanguage extends BaseCommand {

protected $mode = 'lang';
protected $settingsMode = 'setLang';

function processCommand()
{
    switch ($this->userData['mode']) {
        case $this->mode:
            $this->startCommand();
            break;
        case $this->setMode:
            $this->settingsCommand();
            break;
        default:
            $this->defaultCommand();
    }
}

function defaultCommand()
{
 // some code
}

function settingsCommand()
{
 // another code
}

function startCommand()
{
// something else
}
```

И мне бы хотелось каким-то образом, если это возможно, в базовом классе получать эти поля `$mode` и `$settingsMode` и в нем же прописать логику, какой метод нужно вызвать, а так у меня в каждом классе-обработчике этот switch/case

Это кусок кода с телеграм бота и эи классы обработчики вытягиваются с конфиг файла с масивом вида команда => клас

Comment: Если вы под базовым классом подразумеваете абстрактный класс, то он служит лишь для обозначения структуры его наследников, и создать его экземпляр вам не удастся. Поэтому не понятно, зачем в нём нужны $mode и $settingsMode.

Comment: Для того, чтобы в него перести логику switch/case (как во втором классе) и не дублировать её везде. Если это невозможно, то оставлю как есть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В чем собственно проблема? Создать в абстрактном классе свойство а в дочернем переопределить. Ну например:

**ParentClass**

```php
abstract class ParentClass
{
    protected $field = 'parent';

    public function __construct()
    {
        echo $this->field; // child
    }
}
```

**ChildClass**

```php
class ChildClass extends ParentClass
{
    protected $field = 'child';
}
```

**another file**

```php
new ChildClass(); // child
```

Comment: Спасибо! Как же я не додумалась